# What happens with WordPress after I activate a plugin

Tags: wordpress

I would like to know what happens when I click on activate on a WordPress-Plugin on "Activate". Which files and functions get Triggered by WordPress.

How I actually think WordPress is working are these steps:

1. A file and function from WordPress is in a loop which gets triggered like this:
   [image: code1]

WordPress gets from the main-file the Header-fields and calls a file(which?) with the functions and defines it to the public output with echo or return.

2. WordPress calls the `activation_function`. When the user has not defined it then it does nothing.
3. The main file runs now like each other program.
4. While the program runs, WordPress has a file/function which gets triggered on "plugin->deactivate" and a function which will look similarly:"
   [image: code2]

(I am a type of human who likes to play compiler)

(I add a picture because I got only: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" and could not solve like 10 minutes.)

This "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" is driving me crazy. I had to delete a few things.
I have looked on pages like these but no one goes so deep inside:
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate you are thinking this way.

But before you get any answer to this, may i ask why you are asking this?

Meaning, what you want to understand? Is there any specific thing you want to achieve at plugin activation?

There is not much WordPress does while activating plugin.

1. WordPress scans each file or top level directory inside `plugin` directory and looks for header comment

See for more details: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/#getting-started

Once it recognizes a plugin, it offers to activate it.

Here is a ruff sketch what happens once you click `activate`:

1. WordPress runs any callback function that is bound with `register_activation_hook`. Its not required to have an activation hook. If you have a callback function, WordPress runs it, if not, WordPress does not do anything. This callback function is used by plugins to do all sort of stuff like creating default options, creating required database tables, checking for dependent plugins , WordPress and PHP required version compatibility to name a few.
2. WordPress updates an option in DB to keep track of active plugins. so that these can be loaded for each page call. option id is `active_plugins`. Screenshot: https://snipboard.io/e7sjB9.jpg
3. On Next page load, WordPress check this option `active_plugins` and looks for these active plugins and load/run their header comments file code.

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Rao

P.S. this question belongs to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/